# Is there a way I can view changes committed to my local GitHub branch without having to push it to the master branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, github, heroku

I'm still figuring GitHub and Heroku out, so please bear with me. :)

I've a web app on, say, xyz.com. What I am doing now is to make some code/UI changes on some files, commit those files, push them to the master branch, and then refreshing the url to see these changes.

I think this is obviously the wrong approach, but I don't know of how else to test changes done to my code without having to push them on to the master branch. How could I do so?

Comment: To clarify, I'm guessing that you're pushing to github first, and then on xyz.com you're pulling from github?  (Or are you pushing directly to xyz.com?  Not such a good idea...)

Comment: Oh, never mind - I just spotted the heroku tag, so I guess you're pushing directly to there to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the situation in the full version of your question (see my comment and, as [icc asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132364/is-there-a-way-i-can-view-changes-committed-to-my-local-github-branch-without-hav/5132407#5132407), why can't you test locally?), but to answer the question in the title, you can see the differences between your master and the version on GitHub by running:

```
git fetch github
git diff github/master master
```

(That's assuming that the remote that refers to your GitHub repository is called `github` - it might well be `origin` in your case.  You can see all your remotes with `git remote -v`.)

To explain that a little further, when you run `git fetch github`, git will update all your so-called "remote-tracking branches" - in most cases those are the ones that look like `origin/whatever`, `github/experiment`, etc.  Those are like a cache of the state of those branches, and they're only updated when you run `git fetch` or successfully `git push` to that branch on the remote repository.  So, once you've done this to make sure that `github/master` is a recent snapshot of that branch on GitHub, you can happily compare it with your local `master` branch using `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

First: You don't push to the master branch, you push to a remote repo. You should probably read up on your [git](http://gitref.org/).

Second: This is not a good workflow, first you should commit your changes and then test them locally. When you are done testing you are ready to push your commits to a remote repo.

Comment: icc, your suggestion is generally true, but not always practical when developing complex Heroku-based applications that leverage Heroku supplied add-ons. In the more complex case, create two Heroku apps, production and staging, and set up two remote git repositories. You can push to the staging application and debug your changes, and then push to production, and finally push a tagged branch to GitHub.